# Get value of type object

Tags: java, oop, reflection

I having type object with fields and I want to get the value of specific field on it ,
how should i do that in java?

here i getting specific field type for field id that are related to entityinstance 
and now i want to get the **value** (like 1,2,3 etc)of this specific field "id".

```
for (Object entityInstance : fromEntityInstances) {

    try {
        Field declaredField = entityObj.getDeclaredField("id");
```

Comment: Are you looking for `declaredField.get(entityInstance);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you get the declared field, you can call its `get` method, like this:

```
// Don't forget getType() here ---vvv
Field declaredField = entityObj.getType().getDeclaredField("id");
Object res = declaredField.get(entityInstance);
```

If all objects there are of the same type, you could move the call of `getDeclaredField` outside the loop to save yourself some CPU cycles.

Answer (score 4):

I *think* you're looking for [`Field.get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
Object value = declaredField.get(entityInstance);
```

If you know the type of it, you can then cast. For primitives, there are specific methods, such as [`Field.getInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getInt%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
int id = declaredField.getInt(entityInstance);
```